# linebreak in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking

I need your help with my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\linebreak}
\cftsetrmarg{7em}% Default is 2.55em
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx}
\section{yyy}
\end{document}
```

I wrote the command `\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\linebreak}` because I need the extra line between two sections in the toc. But this command also moves the page number closer to the title. How can I avoid this? 
I would like to have it like this (with the red "1"):

[image]

Comment: You can replace `\linebreak` by `\vskip25pt` or another length of your choice.

Comment: @leandriis I also use a linespread (in the original file, not in this MWE), so I can't reproduce the size uf an empty line with \vskip25pt (or any other length). is there an other way to solve the problem?

Comment: Well, without knowing the exact vaule of the linespread you are using (and how you set it up), I am not really able to test possible solutions. So would you please provide this information?

Comment: Close voters: the question has a MWE that clearly shows the problem so this is not unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than redefining `\cftsecafterpnum` you need to redefine `\cftsecaftersnum` -- see pages 28-29 of the [tocloft](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) manual for the full list of "user commands to control the typesetting of Section entries". (Unfortunately, the manual gives only a cursory description of what each of the many commands do, so some guess work is involved.)

In more detail, if you instead use

```
\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{\newline}
```

then your MWE produces:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{\newline}
\cftsetrmarg{7em}% Default is 2.55em
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx}
\section{yyy}
\end{document}
```